# Getting another value from a selected row in pickerview

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a PickerView to show data from a JSON array.

The JSON array has several keys and I am merging the values from two of the keys to populate the pickerview:

```
 let fullName = (friendObj["nombre"] as! String) + " " + (friendObj["apellidos"] as! String)

 self.searchResults.append(fullName)
```

When the user selects a row, the selected value is the string fullName:

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResults.count
    }
    //MARK: Delegates
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return searchResults[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print (searchResults[row])

    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

How could I show the string fullName as row title, but getting the value of another JSON key as result?

EDITED:

```
do {

                    // Convert data returned from server to NSDictionary
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    // Cleare old search data and reload table
                    self.searchResults.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)


                    // If friends array is not empty, populate searchResults array
                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        if let friends  = parseJSON["friends"] as? [AnyObject]
                        {
                            for friendObj in friends
                            {
                                let fullName = (friendObj["nombre"] as! String) + " " + (friendObj["apellidos"] as! String)

                                self.searchResults.append(fullName)


                            }


                            self.pickerAsesores.reloadAllComponents()

                        } else if(parseJSON["message"] != nil)
                        {
                            // if no friends returned, display message returned from server side
                            let errorMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String

                            if(errorMessage != nil)
                            {
                                // display an alert message
                                self.displayAlertMessage(errorMessage!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Rather than storing array of strings that you display in each row you should store an array of objects that represent your JSON objects and then get the relevant strings in `cellForRow:at` in order to populate the rows.

Comment: @Paulw11, I have been searching for how to convert the array of strings to an array of objects

Comment: Strings are already objects, but what I meant is to store the original JSON information. You haven't shown how you are getting the object from the JSON but it looks like you have a dictionary; you should store whatever `friendObj` in the array, rather than the string you get from it

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you, I have edited the question and included how am I getting the JSON response. How should I store the JSON objects to searchResult ?

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11, I have it now. I have answered my own question

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it as follows:

```
  for friendObj in friends
                  { let fullName = ["Nombre": friendObj["nombre"] as! String, "Apellidos": friendObj["apellidos"] as! String, "Id": friendObj["id"] as! String, "Tel": friendObj["tel"] as! String, "Email": friendObj["email"] as! String]

                      self.searchResults.append(fullName)

                                }
...

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print (searchResults[row]["Id"]!)
        let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
        prefs.setValue(searchResults[row]["Id"], forKey: "miAsesorId")
        prefs.setValue(searchResults[row]["Nombre"]! + " " + searchResults[row]["Apellidos"]!, forKey: "miAsesor")
        prefs.setValue(searchResults[row]["Tel"], forKey: "miAsesorTel")
        prefs.setValue(searchResults[row]["Email"], forKey: "miAsesorEmail")

    }
```

As said by @Paulw11, I changed the array for a dictionary and it works fine now.